# Conditions for an operator to be diagonalisable in a Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, diagonalization

I have a doubt that involves Hilbert spaces and diagonalisation. So if we say that a diagonal operator in a basis can be written as, (with Dirac's notation)

$$A=\sum a_i |i\rangle \langle i|$$

In any space I know that this diagonalisation condition can be more complicated. But in a Hilbert space when a operator is expressable as I written before? Can I always write an operator in this form?

It's known that if the operator is hermitian, is diagonalisable. But as fas as I know this condition is not necessary and sufficient, and I don't know what restrctions can be imposed to matrixes in a Hilbert space.

I have not specified the dimension, so there could be some difference bethen the finite and infinite dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $ \mathcal{H}$ being  be a real or complex [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space), with inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$,  and $L:\mathcal{H}\to \mathcal{H}$ being a [compact linear operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator#:%7E:text=In%20functional%20analysis%2C%20a%20branch%20of%20mathematics%2C,a%20compact%20operator%20is%20a%20linear%20operator).

Let us suppose that $L$ is a [selfadjoint operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator), that is $$\langle Lu,v\rangle=\langle u,Lv\rangle,\qquad u,\,v\in \mathcal{H}.$$ Then  there exists a discrete orthonormal set $\{\phi_1,\,\phi_2,,\,\ldots\}$, and a set of scalar $\{\lambda_1,\,\lambda_2,\ldots\}$ (both sets can be finite sets, when the dimesion of $\mathcal{H}$ is finite), being such that $$L(u)=\sum_i\lambda_i\langle \phi_i,u\rangle\phi_i.$$

This results also holds if $L$ is a [normal operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_operator).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I will include details as soon as possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This thread is related  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746426/confused-about-this-proof-of-hilbert-schmidt-theorem#answer-2746692. You can find more on this subject on SearcOnMath.

Answer (score 1):

I find it difficult to parse your question, but I suspect that you mean to ask the following: if $A$ is a diagonalizable over a (finite dimensional) Hilbert space, then it is necessarily possible to find an orthonormal basis $\{|i\rangle\}_{i=1,\dots,n}$ such that $A = \sum_{i} a_i |i\rangle\langle i|$ for coefficients $a_i \in \Bbb C$?

The answer to this question is no. In particular, every operator of this form is **normal**, i.e. satisfies $AA^\dagger = A^\dagger A$. In fact, an operator is normal if and only if it can be written in this fashion for some choice of basis $\{|i\rangle\}$ an associated coefficients. On the other hand, there exist operators that are **diagonalizable not normal**. For example, consider the operator over $\Bbb C^2$ associated with the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{1&2\\0&2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) provides a "diagonalisation" of self-adjoint operators (and more generally also for normal operators). Let $A$ be a (not necessarily bounded) self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, and $\sigma(A)$ its spectrum. The spectral theorem guarantees that a [projection-valued measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection-valued_measure) $E$ exists such that
$$A = \int_{\sigma(A)} \lambda \ \mathrm{d}E(\lambda).$$
If the spectrum of $A$ is discrete and consists of eigenvalues only (e.g. if $\mathcal{H}$ is finite-dimensional), then this representation reduces to the familiar formula
$$A = \sum_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} \lambda P_\lambda,$$
where $P_\lambda$ is the projection operator to the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.